# pdo cannot find driver and no php_pdo extension

Tags: php, pdo

When I tried to put my website on localhost, the php file that connects it to a mydql datdabase says cannot find driver.

I searched up the problem and found other people with the same problem and they solved it by uncommenting an extension in their php.ini file. I tried to do the same but php_pdo.dll isnt in my php.ini file. what should i do?

if ur wondering, heres the code that connects to mysql.

```
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "105th time lucky", "password");

    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Print host information
    echo "Connect Successfully. Host info: " .
        $pdo->getAttribute(constant("PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS"));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Comment: you can add the line in your php.ini, it works. First of all you must check if the pdo dll is present in your computer

Comment: @GiacomoM i don't know if it worked because now i have another problem, localhost refused to connect.

Comment: It worked as your code tried to connect. You have a different issue now, which should be addressed in a different question (well, there are hndreds of questions with this error message on SO alone...)